# Django + mod_wsgi + apache2: ImportError: No module named <project>

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get to the bottom of my problem regarding running any "migrate" command on my django project.
I have a django app deployed in a virtual env and with mod_wsgi and apache2 the app is served properly at www.mysite.com/test/simulatore.
The problem came when I edited the models, so I had to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

After some initial troubleshooting I think I have isolated the problem on wsgi.py
If I try (from my virtualenv) to try to run the command

```
python -i /home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py
```

this is the result

```
['/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma', '/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python35.zip', '/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5', '/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma/..', '/home/carma/mycarma_test', '/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named '”mycarma'
```

As you can see the module mycarma (which is the project name) is reported with single quotes and the just the initial double quote

```
ImportError: No module named '”mycarma'
```

This tells me (I think) there is a configuration issue somewhere that is passing a wrong parameter, but I can't find where. Here are my settings:

**Directory structure**

```
mycarma_test
└── mycarma
├── manage.py
├── mycarma
│   ├── development_settings.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── test_settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements
│   ├── common.txt
│   ├── dev.txt
│   ├── prod.txt
│   └── test.txt
├── simulatore
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── registration
    │   └── login.html
    └── simulatore
        └── index.html
```

**File wsgi in mycarma/mycarma**

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

DJANGO_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
sys.path.append('/home/carma/mycarma_test')
sys.path.append('/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma')
print(sys.path)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mycarma.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Please note I added the two append and the print in order to test/troubleshoot. But also without them no luck.
**settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mycarma.urls'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/carma/mycarma/static'
```

**Apache2 conf file**

```
        <Directory /home/carma/mycarma/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon-1 processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/home/carma/mycarma/ python-home=/home/carma/mycarma/mycarmaenv
    WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon-2 processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/ python-home=/home/carma/mycarma/testenv

    WSGIScriptAlias /simulatore /home/carma/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py

    <Location /simulatore>
            WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon-1
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>
    <Directory /home/carma/mycarma/mycarma>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /test /home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py

    <Location /test>
            WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon-2
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>
    <Directory /home/carma/mycarma_test/mycarma/mycarma>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT: problem found**
In the dev bin/activate script the

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=”carma.test_settings”
```

used some weird double quotes. Modified and everything si working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that is because you have that extra double quote in your `INSTALLED_APPS` django config. This is happening when django bootstraps and tries to load all your apps and it can't locate it.

Comment: No, installed apps is good. And mycarma is not an app, it's a django project.

Comment: Here's INSTALLED_APPS '
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'simulatore',
    'debug_toolbar',
]
'

Comment: Try grepping your source files for that quote using `grep -R --color '”mycarma' /home/carma/mycarma_test`

Comment: The only record found is in the testenv where I set the custom test_settings file `/home/carma/mycarma/testenv/bin/activate:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=”mycarma.test_settings”`

Comment: Problem found. The double quotes were not proper double quotes, probably from a different encoding. Changed them, all works. Thanks for your help.